# How can I put a dropdown list in a ascendant?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I need to put the names in ascendant list.

This is my view...

```
 <select name="characters" id="characters">
            <option value="">-</option>
            <?php foreach($characters as $character):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $character->id; ?>"><?php echo $character->name; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And this is my model. i use this for get the data form DB.

```
 public function get_users_by_type ($user_type_tag, $count='', $offset='', $searchvalue='')
{
    if (empty ($user_type_tag))
        return FALSE;

    $name   = !isset ($searchvalue['name']) ? '' : $searchvalue['name'];

    $this->db->select ('users.*, tag, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(joined) AS timestamp, user_types.name AS user_type_name, user_types.modified AS user_type_modified');
    $this->db->from ('users');
    $this->db->join ('user_types', 'users.user_type_id = user_types.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->where ('user_types.tag', $user_type_tag);
    $this->db->limit($count, $offset);
    $this->db->like ('users.name',$name );
    $result = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: If you're fetching the `$characters` from database order it based on the name field. By the way share more code and specify what is going wrong.

Comment: This is the completly code for this dropdown.

Comment: @JonathanPadilla - where does `$characters` come from?

Comment: @JonathanPadilla - then follow Fallen's advice - add an ORDER BY clause into your SELECT from the database, and you can specify the order that way.

Comment: I cant use the sort()???

Comment: @andrewsi- How can I do that? on the same code or in the model??

Comment: in your db call: $this->db->order_by("fieldname","asc" ); See here for more examples: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you supplied, you are looping through and array of objects. The sort() method will sort a basic array.

see [php.net sort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

The most efficient way to sort the data is to sort it when you're retrieving from the database with an ORDER BY clause as Fallen & andrewsi recommended.

Comment: How can I put in a ASC?